# Book reference request for "Synchronisation in discrete dynamical system"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, synchronization

I'm looking for rigorous mathematical treatment of **synchronisation in discrete dynamical system**, in particular, stability/unstability of syncronisation. It would be great if anyone gives me suggestion for appropriate books (or notes, if available). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few books and a research article.

1. [Chaotic Synchronization of Piecewise Linear Maps](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789814287654_0015)
2. [Chaos, An Introduction to Dynamical Systems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387946771)

A research article -

3. [Synchronization of coupled chaotic maps](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.07264)